# valhalla map matching with a kafka source

Tags: apache-kafka, coordinates, map-matching

I am running a Valhalla map matching program using its meili functionality. I learned that it needs at least set of 2 coordinates to work. It does not work with a single coordinate (lat, long).
I am planning to read the coordinates from kafka and it streams one record at a time. and map-matching does not seem to be working with every single coordinate(lat, long) and throws an "options are invalid" error. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

If I pass more than 1 coordinate directly through the program then it works. Here, coordinates are a single set of (lat, long). (eg - -43,20)

Comment: Why does "one record" need to be "one coordinate"? Or why not run the map function after you read more than one event instead of after each event?